# How to run build tasks with Node.js tools for Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to run [this jar](http://plovr.com/) to serve my JavaScript code for my node application every time the user runs the project. I've tried editing the *.njsproj* file to include my custom build task (see below) but I think I've reached the opinion that the *.njsproj* files do not work in the same way as other visual studio project files.

**Is there anyway I can automate my task?**

Can't find anything helpful or that works on Google. Don't mind what technology is used to do the job as long as it can be automated.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
      <Plovr>plovr\plovr.jar</Plovr>
      <PlovrConfig>plovr\plovr-config-debug.js</PlovrConfig>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      <Message Text="Plovr: $(Plovr)"/>
      <Message Text="PlovrConfig: $(PlovrConfig)"/>
      <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe&quot; -jar $(Plovr) build $(PlovrConfig)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Did you find a way to do this in the .njsproj file, Ally? Thanks.